# Is a non-virgin permitted to cover her hair?

Tags: women, hair, hair-covering

I have always heard that unmarried women, meaning virgins, do not have to cover their hair. Yet I have also heard that unmarried women who are not virgins should cover their hair. What sources support this claim? And if that is the case why is it not kept?

Comment: chavatzellet, welcome to Mi Yodeya! Do you have a reason to suspect that this might not be permitted? If so, please [edit] it into your question. Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, to [enable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting.

Comment: "why is it not kept" Probably bc most unmarried non-virgins wouldn't care that much if we told them to follow a certain Halacha.

Comment: Jewish women should not walk in the marketplace with uncovered hair. [This applies to] both unmarried* and married women. (this does not explain whether the unmarried was a virgin or not..)
Followed by this note,

    *I.e., a widow or a divorcee. A woman who never married may wear her hair uncovered (Chelkat Mechokek 21:2).